# Istio upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We have installed istion-1.4.0 from istio-demo.yml file by running the following command on k8s cluster - 1.15.1

kubectl apply -f istio-demo.yml

Now we need to upgrade our istio from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0 and as per my understanding its not straight forward, due to changes in istio components ( introducing of istiod and removing citadel,galley,policy & telemetry).

How can i move from kubectl to istoctl so that my future upgrade to istio in-line with.??

Comment: What is your question? specifically.

Comment: @Rico .. i have draft the query, few lines got missed

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, you´re looking for a way to install `istioctl` and install istio with it or upgrade your istio build with `kubectl apply` with `istioctl`? If it´s about upgrade I suspect it might work like with helm, there is community guide on  istio discuss about [upgrading from 1.4.3 to 1.6](https://discuss.istio.io/t/upgrading-istio-1-4-3-to-1-6-0/6814/16), could you try to install [istioctl](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/) and follow the steps from 1.4.x to 1.4.10 and from 1.4.10 to 1.5.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments I have followed a theme on [istio discuss](https://discuss.istio.io/t/upgrading-istio-1-4-3-to-1-6-0/6814/16) about upgrade created by@laurentiuspurba.

I have changed it a little for your use case, so an upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5.

Take a look at below steps to follow.

---

1.Follow istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download) and install istioctl 1.4 and 1.5 with:

```
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.4.0 sh -
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.5.0 sh -
```

2.Add the istioctl 1.4 to your path

```
cd istio-1.4.0
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

3.Install istio 1.4

```
istioctl manifest generate > $HOME/generated-manifest.yaml
kubectl create namespace istio-system
kubectl apply -f generated-manifest.yaml
```

4.Check if everything works correct.

```
kubectl get pod -n istio-system
kubectl get svc -n istio-system
istioctl version
```

5.Add the istioctl 1.5 to your path

```
cd istio-1.5.0
export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

6.Install [istio operator](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2019/introducing-istio-operator/) for future upgrade.

```
istioctl operator init
```

7.Prepare IstioOperator.yaml

```
nano IstioOperator.yaml
```

---

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: default
  tag: 1.5.0
```

8.Before the upgrade use below commands

```
kubectl -n istio-system delete service/istio-galley deployment.apps/istio-galley
kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/istio-galley
```

9.Upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5 with istioctl upgrade and prepared IstioOperator.yaml

```
istioctl upgrade -f IstioOperator.yaml
```

10.After the upgrade use below commands

```
kubectl -n istio-system delete deployment istio-citadel istio-galley istio-pilot istio-policy istio-sidecar-injector istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete service istio-citadel istio-policy istio-sidecar-injector istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/istio-pilot horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete pdb istio-citadel istio-galley istio-pilot istio-policy istio-sidecar-injector istio-telemetry
kubectl -n istio-system delete deployment istiocoredns
kubectl -n istio-system delete service istiocoredns
```

11.Check if everything works correct.

```
kubectl get pod -n istio-system
kubectl get svc -n istio-system
istioctl version
```

12.I have deployed a bookinfo app to check if everything work correct.

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml
kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
```

13.Results

```
curl -v xx.xx.xxx.xxx/productpage | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK


istioctl version
client version: 1.5.0
control plane version: 1.5.0
data plane version: 1.5.0 (8 proxies)
```

---

Hope you find this useful. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: But how to do a canary style upgrade for istio from version 1.7.x to 1.8x. How to have same setup of existing istio as newly upgraded without any breakage or minimal outage without loosing any configuration which is for Production ready setup. the current setup installed using istioctl install --set profile -f /istio/overlay.yml